# spring-cloud-config-aws-kms NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: defaultTextEncryptor, kmsTextEncryptor

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud

To use encrypted properties in my `application.yml`, I wanted to use Zalando's `config-aws-kms` project. I followed the instructions in https://github.com/zalando/spring-cloud-config-aws-kms, that is I added it as a dependency to my `pom.xml` But then I got NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field encryptor in org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - defaultTextEncryptor: defined by method 'defaultTextEncryptor' in org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.EncryptionAutoConfiguration$DefaultTextEncryptorConfiguration
    - kmsTextEncryptor: defined by method 'kmsTextEncryptor' in de.zalando.spring.cloud.config.aws.kms.KmsEncryptionConfiguration$KmsTextEncryptorConfiguration

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: defaultTextEncryptor,kmsTextEncryptor
```

pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-aws-kms</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to swap the `spring-cloud-config-starter` with the `spring-cloud-config-aws-kms` order, because Spring's `DefaultTextEncryptorConfiguration` has a `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation, but the other one haven't got a ConditionalOnMissingBean annotation and that's why you get an Exception.

Comment: yes that worked, thanks. https://github.com/zalando/spring-cloud-config-aws-kms/issues/18#issuecomment-319618442